# Terraform unable to recognise pre existing Subnet in AWS

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to set up an EC2 with elastic IP with terraform. I am trying to use the existing VPC and subnets for the new EC2. 
But Terraform is unable to recognise the existing subnet.

I am using the pre existing subnet like this -

```
variable "subnet_id" {}

data "aws_subnet" "my-subnet" {
  id = "${var.subnet_id}"
}
```

When I run terraform plan I get this error -

```
Error: InvalidSubnetID.NotFound: The subnet ID 'subnet-02xxxxxxxxxx7' does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: c4b6142b-5dfd-458c-959d-e5440b89c9fd

  on ec2.tf line 3, in data "aws_subnet" "my-subnet":
   3: data "aws_subnet" "my-subnet" {
```

This subnet was created by terraform in the past. So why does it say it doesn't exist?

Comment: Are you able to look in the AWS console to see if that subnet ID exists?  If it does, how are you authenticating with AWS? Do you assume a role?  If so, does that role have access to your VPC resources?

Comment: Yes the subnet exists in AWS. I am using the admin role to run the terraform script. It has access to all resources.

Comment: And you're looking in the correct AWS account and region? If you include the `aws_region` and `aws_caller_identity` data sources and output their values do you see what you expect?

Comment: If this subnet was created by Terraform in the past, then why not just use the output stored in the state?

Comment: @MattSchuchard - How do I use the output stored in the state? the tfstate is stored in the project directory, but how do i use it ?

Comment: @Seeker90 have you tried what I suggested about outputting the region and account number? This sounds very strongly like you are using the wrong account or region.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested debug:

Create 2 new terraform files:

First file, create a simple subnet (or VPC then subnet whatever)

Second file, try to retreive the subnet id like you posted.

The idea here is not to change anything else, meaning, same region, same creds, same everything.

Possible outputs:

1) you're not able to get the subnet ID - then you should be looking at things like the terraform version, provider version, stuff like that

2) you get the subnet ID, which means something in your creds, region, copy&paste of the name, basically human error is leading this blockade and you should revisit how you're doing things with emphysis on typos and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Data-Sources `aws_vpc`, `aws_subnet` and `aws_subnet_ids`:

```
data "aws_vpc" "default" {
  default = true
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "selected" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.default.id
}

data "aws_subnet" "selected" {
  for_each = data.aws_subnet_ids.selected.ids
  id       = each.value
}
```

And we can use them like in this LB example below:

```
resource "aws_alb" "alb" {
  ...
  subnets = [for subnet in data.aws_subnet.selected : subnet.id]
  ...
}
```

This provides a reference to the VPC and subnets so you can pass the ID to other resources. Terraform does not manage the VPC or subnets when you do this, it simply references them.

Answer (score -1):

It's irrelevant whether the subnet was initially created by Terraform or not.
The data source is attempting to find the subnet in the current state file. Your plan command returns the error because the subnet is not in your state file.

Try importing the subnet and then re-running the plan.

```
$ terraform import aws_subnet.public_subnet subnet-02xxxxxxxxxx7
```

Comment: When I try import , I get this error -
Error: resource address "aws_subnet.public_subnet" does not exist in the configuration.

Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in the root module. For example:

resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {
  # (resource arguments)
}

Comment: @MikeCharles This is wrong. The `aws_subnet` data source looks at all subnets in the AWS account and region regardless of whether Terraform created them. The only data source that cares about Terraform state is the [`terraform_remote_state` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html).

Comment: This answer is wrong. This data source does not look in a state file, it looks in the AWS account for the subnet ID.